# SQlite nested query with counts

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, querying, subquery

I've got the following table in my Sqlite database :

- ID_container : A5, A5, E12, E12, E12
- ID_line : A5_1, A5_2, E12_1, E12_2, E12_3
- Agreement : Yes, Yes, No, Yes, No

To my mind, the query deals with 3 cases :

- it counts the number of line for each ID_container
- it counts the number of "yes" for each line links to ID_container,
- it counts the numer of "no" for for each line ID_container,

Expected results are :

- ID_container : A5, E12
- Number_of_line : 2, 3
- Number_of_yes : 2, 1
- Number_of_no :  0, 2

I'm working on the following query that doesn't work :

```
    SELECT req1.ID_container, req2.Number_of_line, req1.agreement_yes, req3.agreement_no
    FROM 
    (select t_ID_container,COUNT(ID_line) as agreement_yes FROM my_table WHERE agreement='Yes' GROUP BY ID_container) as req1
    INNER JOIN
    (select t_ID_container,COUNT(ID_line) as Number_of_line FROM my_table  GROUP BY ID_container) as req2 
    INNER JOIN
    (select t_ID_container,COUNT(ID_line) as agreement_no FROM my_table  WHERE agreement='No' GROUP BY ID_container) as req3
ON req1.ID_container=req2.ID_container=req3.ID_container
```

I'm a bit confused because I don't know how to progress.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with one query using conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT ID_container, 
count(*) as number_of_line,
count(case when agreement='Yes' then 1 end) as number_of_yes,
count(case when agreement='No' then 1 end) as number_of_no
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY ID_container
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !